# Serialize & Deserialize a dictionary that contain a class key

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, deserialization

Im trying to serialize my dictionary that looks like that:

```
private Dictionary<MetaDataKey, User> _dictionary;
```

where MetaDataKey and Users classes looks like that:

```
internal class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
internal class Account
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string AccName { get; set; }
    public string AccPass { get; set; }
    public List<string> Notes { get; set; }
}
internal class MetaDataKey
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to save\load the dictionary to\from a json file like this:

```
private void DictionaryInit()
    {
        //gets the dictionary file if exists, create an empty one if not.
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dic.json";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            _dictionary = new Dictionary<MetaDataKey, User>();
            return;
        }
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            _dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<MetaDataKey, User>>(json);
        }
    }

    public void DictionarySave()
    {
        //save the dictionary into dic.json file
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dic.json";
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_dictionary);
        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }
```

when I am loading a new record to the dictionary and trying to save it I get:

```
{"WpfApplication2.MetaDataKey":{"UserName":"Enter Name","UserPassword":"Enter Password","Accounts":null}}
```

instead of:

```
{"WpfApplication2.MetaDataKey":{"Name":"Enter Name","Password":"Enter Password"},"WpfApplication2.User":{"UserName":"Enter Name","UserPassword":"Enter Password","Accounts":null}}
```

as you can tell, I am getting the fields of Users in MetaDataKey class.
even after I fix it manualy I am still getting exception:

```
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
```

when I am trying to load a non-empty file.
In conclusion, 2 problems:
1. bad json saving.
2. bad json loading

Comment: Can we see an example of what the json file contains?

Comment: at first time its empty, and after I add a record i get this in the file:{"WpfApplication2.MetaDataKey":{"UserName":"Enter Name","UserPassword":"Enter Password","Accounts":null}}
(same as ive posted)

Comment: It looks like the Newtonsoft JSON serializer uses the ToString representation of the key object as key. The default ToString representation is the full class name (= namespace.classname).

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm):

> When serializing a dictionary, the keys of the dictionary are converted to strings and used as the JSON object property names. The string written for a key can be customized by either overriding ToString() for the key type or by implementing a TypeConverter. A TypeConverter will also support converting a custom string back again when deserializing a dictionary.

You have two options:

1. like the documentation suggests: create a `TypeConverter` for your `MetaDataKey` and link it with attribute (`[TypeConverter(typeof(MetaDataKeyConverter))]`) - This is not trivial as you will have to convert the `MetaDataKey` to json string yourself, and also deserialize from string.
2. Create a `JsonConverter` for dictionary and use it in your `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` methods.
3. **The simplest** thing you can do is to convert the dictinary to a `List<KeyValuePair<MetaData,User>>` this is easy as `_dictionary.ToList()`
   So for serializing:

   ```
   string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_dictionary.ToList());
   ```

   And for deserialize:

   ```
   _dictionary = 
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<MetaDataKey, User>>>(json)
              .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
   ```

For most cases I would choose option 3

Answer (score 0):

Adding an example of using TypeConverter:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(YourConverter))]
public class YourClass
{
    public string PropA { get; set; } = default!;
    public string PropB{ get; set; } = default!;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{{\"PropA\":\"{PropA }\",\"PropB\":\"{PropB}\"}}";
    }
 }
```

Now the implementation of the type converter:

```
    public class YourConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(value.ToString());
        var extensionContext = new ExtensionContext
        {
            PropA = jObject["PropA"].ToString(),
            PropB = jObject["PropB"].ToString()
        };
        return extensionContext;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use JsonProperty attribute like the following:

```
internal class User
{

 [JsonProperty("UserName ")]
 public string UserName { get; set; }

 [JsonProperty("UserPassword")]
 public string UserPassword { get; set; }

 [JsonProperty("Accounts ")]
 public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: Please see this [guide](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm)